# css modules in create-react-app not working in production (heroku)

Tags: heroku, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-style-loader, react-css-modules

I read all possible question about this topic but not found anything that help me.

I build react app using create-react-app and want to use css modules.
So I change the weback files found in **node_modules/react-scripts/config** because I don't want to 'eject' the config files.

On dev everything works well and it's recognize the modules , but on production it's not working. ( in dev not exist 'ExtractTextPlugin' plugin anyway)

So, laster I try to 'eject' the configuration files and then do change the web pack prod file that found in the src/config and it's work, but I really don't want to eject all configuration files for this.

I try also to copy exactly the same web pack.config.prod.js file that work after eject but for some reason it's doesn't help

this is the code from my web pack.config.prod.js:

```
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          Object.assign(
            {
              fallback: {
                loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                options: {
                  hmr: false,
                },
              },
              use: [
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                  options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:64:5]',
                    //   minimize: true,
                    //   sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                  },
                },
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                  options: {
                    // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                    ident: 'postcss',
                    plugins: () => [
                      require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                      autoprefixer({
                        browsers: [
                          '>1%',
                          'last 4 versions',
                          'Firefox ESR',
                          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                        ],
                        flexbox: 'no-2009',
                      }),
                    ],
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            extractTextPluginOptions
          )
        ),
        // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
```

I try many other configuration for this in the prod file  but nothing effect on prod.

tnx all

Comment: What you are really asking? It was not all clear.

Comment: Very simple : how to make modules cas to work with creative react app in production. Nothings work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Eject create-react-app

Modify `webpack.config.prod.js`

Replace:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
   importLoaders: 1,
   minimize: true,
   sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
  },
},
```

To this:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
   importLoaders: 1,
   minimize: true,
   modules: true
   sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
  },
},
```

Comment: tnx , I try this but it's work just on dev - not on production mode unfortunately

Comment: It works, if it doesnt, open an issue on css-loader with your config and see what they say

Comment: What it does is that it extract css from js and put into css file. That only what it does.